# how to get value based on matched key value pair from a single list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Below is the list of dictionaries where the first dictionary has all keys based on which matching has to be done on remining dictionaries.

```
tier_information= [
                {
                    "NaN": "From",
                    "From": "To",
                    "3.00000000": "8.00000000",
                    "4.00000000": "11.00000000",
                    "5.00000000": "14.00000000",
                    "6.00000000": "17.00000000",
                    "7.00000000": "20.00000000",
                    "8.00000000": "23.00000000"
                },
                {
                    "NaN": "3.00000000",
                    "From": "8.00000000",
                    "3.00000000": "13.00000000",
                    "4.00000000": "18.00000000",
                    "5.00000000": "23.00000000",
                    "6.00000000": "28.00000000",
                    "7.00000000": "33.00000000",
                    "8.00000000": "38.00000000"
                },
                {
                    "NaN": "4.00000000",
                    "From": "11.00000000",
                    "3.00000000": "18.00000000",
                    "4.00000000": "25.00000000",
                    "5.00000000": "32.00000000",
                    "6.00000000": "39.00000000",
                    "7.00000000": "46.00000000",
                    "8.00000000": "53.00000000"
                },
                {
                    "NaN": "5.00000000",
                    "From": "14.00000000",
                    "3.00000000": "23.00000000",
                    "4.00000000": "32.00000000",
                    "5.00000000": "41.00000000",
                    "6.00000000": "50.00000000",
                    "7.00000000": "59.00000000",
                    "8.00000000": "68.00000000"
                },
                {
                    "NaN": "6.00000000",
                    "From": "17.00000000",
                    "3.00000000": "28.00000000",
                    "4.00000000": "39.00000000",
                    "5.00000000": "50.00000000",
                    "6.00000000": "61.00000000",
                    "7.00000000": "72.00000000",
                    "8.00000000": "83.00000000"
                },
                {
                    "NaN": "7.00000000",
                    "From": "20.00000000",
                    "3.00000000": "33.00000000",
                    "4.00000000": "46.00000000",
                    "5.00000000": "59.00000000",
                    "6.00000000": "72.00000000",
                    "7.00000000": "85.00000000",
                    "8.00000000": "98.0000000"
                },
                {
                    "NaN": "8.00000000",
                    "From": "23.00000000",
                    "3.00000000": "38.00000000",
                    "4.00000000": "53.00000000",
                    "5.00000000": "68.00000000",
                    "6.00000000": "83.00000000",
                    "7.00000000": "98.00000000",
                    "8.00000000": "113.00000000"
                }
            ]
```

Explanation:
As we can see that the tier_information[0] has below format:-

```
"NaN": "From",
"From": "To",
```

Now,suppose tier_information[0] contains a pair `"3.00000000": "8.00000000"`, and if it matches in the 2nd dict in the list as below, i.e.

```
"NaN": "3.00000000",
"From": "8.00000000",
"3.00000000":
```

Then the output should be `13.00000000`.
Similarly, if tier_information[0] contains a pair `"4.00000000": "11.00000000"`, and if it matches in the 2nd dict in the list as below, i.e.

```
"NaN": "3.00000000",
"From": "8.00000000", 
"4.00000000":
```

The output should be `"18.00000000"` and so on. In the nutshell, we have to compare dict[0] with each sub dict and fetch the value. I have written the below piece of program.

```
count = 0
reference_dict = tier_information[0]
for i in reference_dict:
    count += 1
    result_dict = {}
    for sub_dict in tier_information:
        for key, value in sub_dict.items():
            if key in reference_dict:
                result_dict[key] = value

    print(result_dict)
```

And on executing it, I am getting below output

```
{'NaN': '8.00000000', 'From': '23.00000000', '3.00000000': '38.00000000', '4.00000000': '53.00000000', '5.00000000': '68.00000000', '6.00000000': '83.00000000', '7.00000000': '98.00000000', '8.00000000': '113.00000000'}
{'NaN': '8.00000000', 'From': '23.00000000', '3.00000000': '38.00000000', '4.00000000': '53.00000000', '5.00000000': '68.00000000', '6.00000000': '83.00000000', '7.00000000': '98.00000000', '8.00000000': '113.00000000'}
{'NaN': '8.00000000', 'From': '23.00000000', '3.00000000': '38.00000000', '4.00000000': '53.00000000', '5.00000000': '68.00000000', '6.00000000': '83.00000000', '7.00000000': '98.00000000', '8.00000000': '113.00000000'}
{'NaN': '8.00000000', 'From': '23.00000000', '3.00000000': '38.00000000', '4.00000000': '53.00000000', '5.00000000': '68.00000000', '6.00000000': '83.00000000', '7.00000000': '98.00000000', '8.00000000': '113.00000000'}
{'NaN': '8.00000000', 'From': '23.00000000', '3.00000000': '38.00000000', '4.00000000': '53.00000000', '5.00000000': '68.00000000', '6.00000000': '83.00000000', '7.00000000': '98.00000000', '8.00000000': '113.00000000'}
{'NaN': '8.00000000', 'From': '23.00000000', '3.00000000': '38.00000000', '4.00000000': '53.00000000', '5.00000000': '68.00000000', '6.00000000': '83.00000000', '7.00000000': '98.00000000', '8.00000000': '113.00000000'}
{'NaN': '8.00000000', 'From': '23.00000000', '3.00000000': '38.00000000', '4.00000000': '53.00000000', '5.00000000': '68.00000000', '6.00000000': '83.00000000', '7.00000000': '98.00000000', '8.00000000': '113.00000000'}
{'NaN': '8.00000000', 'From': '23.00000000', '3.00000000': '38.00000000', '4.00000000': '53.00000000', '5.00000000': '68.00000000', '6.00000000': '83.00000000', '7.00000000': '98.00000000', '8.00000000': '113.00000000'}
```

The output is not what is required.
Please help, thank you.

Required output:

```
[ 3.00000000 8.00000000 3.00000000 8.00000000 ] = 13.00000000
[ 3.00000000 8.00000000 4.00000000 11.00000000 ] = 18.00000000
[ 3.00000000 8.00000000 5.00000000 14.00000000 ] = 23.00000000
[ 3.00000000 8.00000000 6.00000000 17.00000000 ] = 28.00000000
[ 3.00000000 8.00000000 7.00000000 20.00000000 ] = 33.00000000
[ 3.00000000 8.00000000 8.00000000 23.00000000 ] = 38.00000000
[ 4.00000000 11.00000000 3.00000000 8.00000000 ] = 18.00000000
[ 4.00000000 11.00000000 4.00000000 11.00000000 ] = 25.00000000
[ 4.00000000 11.00000000 5.00000000 14.00000000 ] = 32.00000000
[ 4.00000000 11.00000000 6.00000000 17.00000000 ] = 39.00000000
[ 4.00000000 11.00000000 7.00000000 20.00000000 ] = 46.00000000
[ 4.00000000 11.00000000 8.00000000 23.00000000 ] = 53.00000000
[ 5.00000000 14.00000000 3.00000000 8.00000000 ] = 23.00000000
[ 5.00000000 14.00000000 4.00000000 11.00000000 ] = 32.00000000
[ 5.00000000 14.00000000 5.00000000 14.00000000 ] = 41.00000000
[ 5.00000000 14.00000000 6.00000000 17.00000000 ] = 50.00000000
[ 5.00000000 14.00000000 7.00000000 20.00000000 ] = 59.00000000
[ 5.00000000 14.00000000 8.00000000 23.00000000 ] = 68.00000000
[ 6.00000000 17.00000000 3.00000000 8.00000000 ] = 28.00000000
[ 6.00000000 17.00000000 4.00000000 11.00000000 ] = 39.00000000
[ 6.00000000 17.00000000 5.00000000 14.00000000 ] = 50.00000000
[ 6.00000000 17.00000000 6.00000000 17.00000000 ] = 61.00000000
[ 6.00000000 17.00000000 7.00000000 20.00000000 ] = 72.00000000
[ 6.00000000 17.00000000 8.00000000 23.00000000 ] = 83.00000000
[ 7.00000000 20.00000000 3.00000000 8.00000000 ] = 33.00000000
[ 7.00000000 20.00000000 4.00000000 11.00000000 ] = 46.00000000
[ 7.00000000 20.00000000 5.00000000 14.00000000 ] = 59.00000000
[ 7.00000000 20.00000000 6.00000000 17.00000000 ] = 72.00000000
[ 7.00000000 20.00000000 7.00000000 20.00000000 ] = 85.00000000
[ 7.00000000 20.00000000 8.00000000 23.00000000 ] = 98.00000000
[ 8.00000000 23.00000000 3.00000000 8.00000000 ] = 38.00000000
[ 8.00000000 23.00000000 4.00000000 11.00000000 ] = 53.00000000
[ 8.00000000 23.00000000 5.00000000 14.00000000 ] = 68.00000000
[ 8.00000000 23.00000000 6.00000000 17.00000000 ] = 83.00000000
[ 8.00000000 23.00000000 7.00000000 20.00000000 ] = 98.00000000
```

Comment: You haven't said what output you expect / require

Comment: It is already mentioned in the main post. Please see again.

Comment: Why both `"3.00000000": "8.00000000"` and `"4.00000000": "11.00000000"` match the same 2nd  dictionary?

Comment: In the sub directories, the lefthand side data are working as key for all sub directories. We have to match the reference directories to each sub directories one by one. In another word in my request body,  I am getting data in that format, and based on it I need to fetch value.

Comment: @user3521180 You have shown the output that you are getting - not what is wanted

Comment: I have added the exact output that is required.. if someone still willing to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output isn't a valid python structure (what is `=` supposed to mean in this context?) but you can store the desired values in a list of tuples by looping over the key/values of the first dictionary then over the other dictionaries (nested loop):

```
from pprint import pprint

res = []
for k,v in tier_information[0].items():
    if k not in ('NaN', 'From'):
        for d in tier_information[1:]:
            res.append(
                ([k, v, d['NaN'], d['From']], d[k])
            )

pprint(res)
```

Output:

```
[(['3.00000000', '8.00000000', '3.00000000', '8.00000000'], '13.00000000'),
 (['3.00000000', '8.00000000', '4.00000000', '11.00000000'], '18.00000000'),
 (['3.00000000', '8.00000000', '5.00000000', '14.00000000'], '23.00000000'),
 (['3.00000000', '8.00000000', '6.00000000', '17.00000000'], '28.00000000'),
 (['3.00000000', '8.00000000', '7.00000000', '20.00000000'], '33.00000000'),
 (['3.00000000', '8.00000000', '8.00000000', '23.00000000'], '38.00000000'),
 (['4.00000000', '11.00000000', '3.00000000', '8.00000000'], '18.00000000'),
 (['4.00000000', '11.00000000', '4.00000000', '11.00000000'], '25.00000000'),
 (['4.00000000', '11.00000000', '5.00000000', '14.00000000'], '32.00000000'),
 (['4.00000000', '11.00000000', '6.00000000', '17.00000000'], '39.00000000'),
 (['4.00000000', '11.00000000', '7.00000000', '20.00000000'], '46.00000000'),
 (['4.00000000', '11.00000000', '8.00000000', '23.00000000'], '53.00000000'),
 (['5.00000000', '14.00000000', '3.00000000', '8.00000000'], '23.00000000'),
 (['5.00000000', '14.00000000', '4.00000000', '11.00000000'], '32.00000000'),
 (['5.00000000', '14.00000000', '5.00000000', '14.00000000'], '41.00000000'),
 (['5.00000000', '14.00000000', '6.00000000', '17.00000000'], '50.00000000'),
 (['5.00000000', '14.00000000', '7.00000000', '20.00000000'], '59.00000000'),
 (['5.00000000', '14.00000000', '8.00000000', '23.00000000'], '68.00000000'),
 (['6.00000000', '17.00000000', '3.00000000', '8.00000000'], '28.00000000'),
 (['6.00000000', '17.00000000', '4.00000000', '11.00000000'], '39.00000000'),
 (['6.00000000', '17.00000000', '5.00000000', '14.00000000'], '50.00000000'),
 (['6.00000000', '17.00000000', '6.00000000', '17.00000000'], '61.00000000'),
 (['6.00000000', '17.00000000', '7.00000000', '20.00000000'], '72.00000000'),
 (['6.00000000', '17.00000000', '8.00000000', '23.00000000'], '83.00000000'),
 (['7.00000000', '20.00000000', '3.00000000', '8.00000000'], '33.00000000'),
 (['7.00000000', '20.00000000', '4.00000000', '11.00000000'], '46.00000000'),
 (['7.00000000', '20.00000000', '5.00000000', '14.00000000'], '59.00000000'),
 (['7.00000000', '20.00000000', '6.00000000', '17.00000000'], '72.00000000'),
 (['7.00000000', '20.00000000', '7.00000000', '20.00000000'], '85.00000000'),
 (['7.00000000', '20.00000000', '8.00000000', '23.00000000'], '98.00000000'),
 (['8.00000000', '23.00000000', '3.00000000', '8.00000000'], '38.00000000'),
 (['8.00000000', '23.00000000', '4.00000000', '11.00000000'], '53.00000000'),
 (['8.00000000', '23.00000000', '5.00000000', '14.00000000'], '68.00000000'),
 (['8.00000000', '23.00000000', '6.00000000', '17.00000000'], '83.00000000'),
 (['8.00000000', '23.00000000', '7.00000000', '20.00000000'], '98.0000000'),
 (['8.00000000', '23.00000000', '8.00000000', '23.00000000'], '113.00000000')]
```